# Converting character to hex in assembler

Tags: assembly, hex, character, radix, data-conversion

So right now I'm working on reading in a single character from the keyboard and displaying its hex value. At the moment I believe I'm getting the correct hex value, but it is not being displayed correctly. For example, 'k' is 6F in hex, but it's displaying as '6;'. I know that the correction must be made in my DIS16 procedure, but I'm not sure when and what to do. If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it.

```
DIS16   PROC

    mov cx, 0   


    mov bx, 16


numdiv:     

    mov dx, 0   


    div bx


    push dx


    add cx, 1


    cmp ax, 0   


    jne numdiv      


dispnum:


    pop dx


    add dl, 30h



    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h


    loop    dispnum

RET
DIS16   ENDP
```

Comment: *"'k' is 6F in hex"*. No, 'k' is 6B in hex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the characters 'A' thru 'F' do not immediately follow '9', you have to adjust for that.

```
; as you have it
pop dx
add dl, 30h
cmp dl, '9'
jbe skip
add dl, 7 ; bump up to 'A' - 'F'
skip:
; print it... as you were
```